# ¿como le puedo poner contraseña y usuario a la pagina principal de xamp?

Tags: php, html, mysql, web, servidor

Quisiera dejar una pagina principal en xampp con usuario y contraseña, que enlace a otra pagina con un formulario, que  luego conecte mediante (botones) a otras paginas donde pienso dejar formularios especiales conectados a una base de datos en phpmysql. (soy nuevo en el tema). Si esto es posible, podría dejar usuarios con privilegios como editar o borrar o tendría que hacer formularios para cada cosa en especifico. si  es posible me podrían dejar una breve descripción de los pasos a seguir para guiarme y empezar a estudiar. Muchas gracias por su tiempo,  y  disculpen si la pregunta es muy de novato.

Comment: Deberias apoyarte en google para aprender mas del tema. En cuanto a la pregunta debes saber que no se ajusta al propósito de nuestra comunidad, pues se orienta a obtener opiniones. Es muy posible que sea cerrada.

Comment: cual es el proposito de la comunidad pues entre en ella por que encontre respuesta a mis dudas en el tema de php y sql